# Postfix mailbox_command resilliency

Tags: postfix

I need to collect all incoming emails and post them to a URL.

Setting this up seems straight-forward enough, eg (postfix.main.cf):
`mailbox_command = /somewhere/somescript.bash`

Then somescript.bash would curl the email to a server.

BUT, my concern is about http errors. What if the bash script fails or the curl command in the bash script fails?

1. On fail, does the bash script need to throw a fail exit code?
2. On fail, will Postfix retry or just assume everything worked?
3. Is there a documented method for telling Postfix something went wrong?

From my limited understanding of Postfix, it does have an inbound processing queue, but I need to be 100% certain that NO emails are lost in this configuration.

Any guidance or pointers would be most welcome.